# Simple Proxy Creation and connecting back end Web service steps

Tags: wso2

I would like to connect web service using WSO2 API platform, please tell the steps ..this feature is easy in Apigee, where WSO2 unable to create a simple proxy to connect Web Services.

I have Main Frame API backend,  try to connect this API but simple backend connectivity is not available like Apigee.

Please let me know if any option is availble in WSo2.

Regards
Selvavel A

WSO2 API Platform

Comment: I have Main Frame API URL, I will get my details if I click that URL. What I am trying to do ....Create Simple Proxy for access this mainframe URL ....followed by traffic policies will be implemented using WSO2.  This use case is simple in APigee, but WSO2 unable to do it ...

Comment: Could you please explain the steps that you have followed to expose the service via api manager? What are the errors you got?
Here is our official documentation of how to publish an api in api manager.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+and+Publish+an+API